# How to query for a value in an array in an embedded object?

Tags: mongodb, doctrine

I have a collection with objects like this:

```
{
id => ...
[queue] => Array
    (
        [jobs] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [_id] => 308
                        [completedDate] => 1324649528
                    )
            )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [_id] => 308
                        [completedDate] => 1324649512
                    )
            )
    )
}
```

So basically I have a collection with objects with each an embedded (`EmbedOne`) document `Queue`.
This `Queue` document has also a collection (`@EmbedMany`) of `Job` embedded documents.

I want to query for a document with a completed job:

```
db.Page.find({"queue.jobs.completedDate": { $ne : null} }).limit(10);
```

I do this query with Doctrine2 ODM (1.0.0beta3)

```
$query = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder( $modelClass );
$query->field('queue.jobs')->elemMatch( $query->expr()->field('completedDate')->notEqual(null) );
//Or, its the same: $query->field('queue.jobs.completedDate')->notEqual(null);

$query->skip( $page*$perPage )->limit( $perPage );
return $query->getQuery()->execute();
```

but it return nothing, I'm missing something?

Edit: this is the Queue document:

```
/** 
* @EmbeddedDocument 
*/
class Queue {

/** @Boolean */
private $locked = false;

/** @Timestamp */
private $lockedAt;

/** @EmbedMany(targetDocument="Cron\Model\Document\Job") */
private $jobs = array();

    //...setters & getters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works here on the shell with the below code (2.0.2).

```
db.Page.insert({
"queue": {
        "jobs": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId(),
            "completedDate": ISODate()
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId(),
            "completedDate": ISODate()
        }
    ]}
})
```

> db.Page.find({"queue.jobs.completedDate": { $ne : null} }).limit(10);

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ef49ebe093f0426a41ec640"),
    "queue" : {
        "jobs" : [ 
         { 
            "_id" : ObjectId("4ef49ebe093f0426a41ec63e"),
            "completedDate" : ISODate("2011-12-23T15:31:10.881Z")
         }, 
         {
            "_id" : ObjectId("4ef49ebe093f0426a41ec63f"),
            "completedDate" : ISODate("2011-12-23T15:31:10.881Z")
         }
         ] 
    }
}
```

Queue should be a hash as it has the "jobs" key. Your dates look like they are not being stored correctly. Make sure the documents look like what you expect in the database via the shell.

Comment: I've opted to store the dates as Int.
The Queue object si an `@EmbeddedDocument`